# React: Private Routes Using Outlet & Router V6

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm currently creating private routes using `react-router` 6 and `Outlet`.  I have a simple setup as follows:

Routes in App.js

```
return (
  <BrowserRouter>
    <div className="App">
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Login />}></Route>
        <Route path="/register" element={<Register />}></Route>
        <Route element={<PrivateRoutes />}>
          <Route path="/dashboard" element={<Dashboard />}></Route>
          <Route path="/reports" element={<Reports />}></Route>
          <Route path="/settings" element={<Settings />}></Route>
        </Route>
      </Routes>
    </div>
  </BrowserRouter>
);
```

PrivateRoutes component

```
const PrivateRoutes = () => {
  console.log("Private Routes was run");
  validToken = true;

  return (
    (checkToken()) ? <Outlet/> : <Navigate to="/" />
  );
}
```

What I noticed though is the `PrivateRoutes` component does not run when navigating **between** any of the private routes, only when first entering one of the `PrivateRoutes`.

For example, I want the `PrivateRoutes` component to run when I navigate between the `/dashboard` and `/reports` routes using my primary nav.

I tried using both `Link` and `useNavigate` imports from `react-router-dom`, but neither re-triggers the `PrivateRoutes` component.

```
<div id='nav-links' className='flex flex-row'>
  <div onClick={() => navigate('/dashboard')}>Dashboard</div>
  <div onClick={() => navigate('/reports')}>Reports</div>
  <div onClick={() => navigate('/settings')}>Settings</div>
</div>
```

and

```
<div id='nav-links' className='flex flex-row'>
  <Link to='/dashboard'>Dashboard</Link>
  <Link to='/reports'>Reports</div>
  <Link to='/settings'>Settings</div>
</div>
```

What am I missing or not understanding?  Is there a simple syntax adjustment one can use so `PrivateRoutes` is always run upon navigation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your routes are fine. You will want to couple the `checkToken` to the route change. You can listen to route changes using the `useLocation` and `useEffect` hooks. I'm assuming `checkToken` is synchronous.

Example:

```
const PrivateRoutes = () => {
  const { pathname } = useLocation();

  const [isValidToken, setIsValidToken] = useState(); // <-- initially undefined

  useEffect(() => {
    // initial mount or route changed, check token
    setIsValidToken(!!checkToken());
  }, [pathname]);

  if (isValidToken === undefined) {
    return null; // or loading indicator/spinner/etc
  }

  return isValidToken ? <Outlet/> : <Navigate to="/" replace />;
}
```

Comment: Drew to the rescue!  You are the React goat my friend . I was hoping there was a simple property like ‘required’ or something one could add to <Route element={<PrivateRoutes />}> that would watch for changes.  Dare to dream.  Writing a useEffect that watches useLocation makes perfect sense.  Curious, does one need to use ‘replace’ on the return, or is that optional?

Comment: @Parker Oh, I was assuming you wanted to use a redirect instead of a regular navigation, i.e. a REPLACE vs PUSH action. It's not required by any means, but it is the conventional way to redirect off a protected route, usually to a login path. In other words, it helps maintain the history stack.

Comment: Yes, I think REPLACE does make more sense.  I was trying to get my head around returning a user to the path they were on if their token times out, but I’ll slay that dragon another day.

Comment: @Parker I see. I think a common solution with tokens and expirations is to check the token when the app loads and set a timeout to handle the moment the token expires. This is a bit different than guarding access to routes based on authentication. You could create a timeout callback that redirects a user to login in again, or as better UI/UX, render the login in a modal so they can reauthenticate, get a new token (*and expiration*) and remain on the route they are already on (*or bounce them out if they decline to reauth*). There are different ways to handle the token expiration.