# React - "No routes matched location '/dashboard'"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I am currently using React-Router-v6 and I am receiving the warning of "**No routes matched location "/dashboard"**" every time I load the dashboard page.

I am trying to make a public routes section and private routes section. Currently I only have the Dashboard route in the PrivateRoute section.

**UPDATE:** So it seems like if I create any type of new route, even public, it throws the warning. Is this a bug possibly in react router?

https://codesandbox.io/s/clever-lucy-bx7nt6

Is there a reason I am getting this warning with only this route? My code is below:

**App.js Routes:**

```
          <Routes>
              {/* Public Routes */}
              <Route>
                <Route path='/' element={<Homepage />}/>
              </Route>
              <Route path='/contact' element={<Contact />}/>
              <Route path='/login' element={<Login />}/>
              <Route path='/register' element={<Register />}/>
              {/* Private/Protected Routes */}
              <Route element={<PrivateRoute />}>
                <Route path='/dashboard' element={<Dashboard/>}/>
              </Route>
          </Routes>
```

**PrivateRoute.jsx:**

```
import React from 'react'
import { Navigate, Outlet, Route, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useAuth } from '../contexts/AuthContext';

export default function PrivateRoute({ children }) {
    const { currentUser } = useAuth();
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    return currentUser ? <Outlet/> : <Navigate to='/login'/>;
}
```

Thank you in advanced!

Comment: I don't *see* an issue with *this* code. Are you rendering a "dashboard" route anywhere else in the app? Can you [edit] the post to include a more complete [mcve]? Can you create a *running* [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo that reproduces the issue that we could inspect live?

Comment: I think its because your nesting the route so. the outer route should be /dashboard and dashboard has subroutes like /console or /analitics

Comment: @DrewReese i created one just now. I modified my code a bit since I use Firebase and didn't want to add it, but it seems to work in the sandbox perfectly. https://codesandbox.io/s/clever-lucy-bx7nt6

Comment: Like I said, I didn't see any issue with the code snippets you provided. Perhaps there's an issue in the `AuthContext` and Auth Provider component. Can you [edit] the post to include a more complete [mcve] so we have a more complete picture of what the app is rendering from root to routed component?

Comment: @DrewReese I just updated, I did comment out my firebase code though so that I didn't have to implement my API keys.

Comment: When I provide a default `AuthContext` value (*`{ currentUser: true }`*) I'm able to navigate to `"/dashboard"` in your sandbox.

Comment: @DrewReese yeah the code works perfectly fine. I'm just still receiving that warning for some reason.

Comment: Can you provide a *running* code example that does that? I'm just not seeing that warning/error in the console anywhere. Are you *conditionally* rendering a `"/dashboard"` route somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

you should use path on top level `Route`; so can do it this way:

```
<Route path='/dashboard' element={<PrivateRoute><Dashboard/></PrivateRoute>} />
```

Comment: Hey, this does work. However, no matter what I do, it always seems to throw the warning  "No routes matched location "/dashboard" " two times in the console.

Comment: @Blazing seems like your way of doing was more legit; check this question https://stackoverflow.com/a/73264057/5953610

Comment: I checked out the answer to that previous question. I am not really sure on what I am suppose to change really.

Answer (score -1):

Ey!

Im pretty sure that the problem in there is the "outlet" function within "PrivateRoute" to diplay the protected routes.
"Outlet" is only used to display subroutes within a parent component.  In this case, you are trying to use it to display the protected route /dashboard without a parent component, which is incorrect and may be the cause of the error.

```
// App.js

<Routes>
  {/* Public Routes */}
  <Route path='/' element={<Homepage />} />
  <Route path='/contact' element={<Contact />} />
  <Route path='/login' element={<Login />} />
  <Route path='/register' element={<Register />} />
  {/* Private/Protected Routes */}
  <PrivateRoute path='/dashboard'>
    <Route element={<Dashboard />} />
  </PrivateRoute>
</Routes>

// PrivateRoute.jsx

export default function PrivateRoute({ children, path }) {
  const { currentUser } = useAuth();
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  return currentUser ? <Route path={path} element={children} /> : <Navigate to='/login' />;
}
```

This how i always do the same, so i copied mine and adapted to yours. With this, the protected route /dashboard will only be displayed if the user is authenticated.

Comment: Whenever I try that, I receive the error "[PrivateRoute] is not a <Route> component. All component children of <Routes> must be a <Route> or <React.Fragment>"